# recursively add to strings in java

Tags: java, string, recursion

I am trying to convert int 123 to String "CBA" in java

I know I have some something misunderstood in recursion

After many println statements, I know that at a point

ss is going to be "CBA"

but then it will return "CB" and "C"

I kind of know recursion will work like this, but I don't know how to fix it

Can anyone help me with the code, thanks!

```
public String recur ( int x, String ss )
{
    if ( x >= 1 && x < 10 )
        ss = ss + "A";

    if ( x >= 10 && x < 100 )
    {
        ss = ss + "B";
        recur( x % 10, ss);
    }

    if ( x >= 100 && x < 1000 )
    {
        ss = ss + "C";
        recur( x % 100, ss);    
    }
return ss;
```

Comment: Even though Java allows it, it is bad practice to reuse method parameter values. Hint: use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Note that while @fge's comment is correct, it does not help to solve the OP's problem.  Also the "hint" is highly questionable.  At best it is a marginal microoptimization.  If the OP was concerned about performance, then the correct optimization would be to implement this iteratively ...

Comment: @StephenC I wouldn't call something which guarantees data safety a "micro-optimization"

Comment: @fge - How does using a StringBuilder "guarantee data safety"?  And what is this "data safety" you are talking about anyway?  The issue here is code correctness, robustness and readability, not "data safety".

Comment: @StephenC simple: whatever optimization on a stringbuilder affects the stringbuilder itself; as a result, you can recurse and pass it as an argument, and then return `sb.toString()` as the argument. This is unlike `String` which is immutable.

Comment: Are you aware that your code only works if the integer contains the digits 1, 2 or 3? see my answer for a general solution that works for all digits, in any order

Comment: @fge - I don't understand what you are saying.  You stated / implied that `StringBuilder` guarantees data safety.  Please justify THAT point.

Comment: @fge do you mean I should declare string outside of the method?

Comment: @userNew ... no he means that you should not assign to `ss`; e.g. declare it as `final`.  The rest of what he is saying is ... a bit unclear and/or off point.

Comment: @userNew what I mean is that you should declare an outer method to `recur`, pass a StringBuilder to `recur` and return this StringBuilder's `.toString()` as a result.

Comment: @StephenC it is, on the opposite, perfectly clear: what is immutable is immutable; if you want a mutable string to pass along a method which returns `void`, a `StringBuilder` it is.

Comment: @fge I see you mean I should use sb.append() and return sb.toString()...so string = string + X is not a good idea?

Comment: @fge - Your comments are not making any sense to me.  I suggest you write an Answer ... and explain exactly what you mean in the Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the return value of recur so only the first level of recursion is being seen at the ouptput.

So you could do this to take into account the return value. (Just assign the output of recur to ss)

```
ss = recur( x % 10, ss);
```

and the other call.

```
ss = recur( x % 100, ss);
```

Comment: thanks, right I think I'm ignoring something
I have changed recur( x % 10, ss); to ss = recur( x % 10, ss); ...
but I am still getting only C in the ouput

Comment: did you do it for both your recur calls? I think not

Comment: OP's solution, as it is, will only work if the integer contains the digits 1, 2 or 3 - it's not general enough, and will fail for any number containing different digits

Comment: @ÓscarLópez - I think we are all guessing at what the actual problem statement really is.  Certainly you can't infer it from a single example ... and a broken attempt at solving it

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I thought it was trying to convert 1 digit numbers to A, 2 digit numbers to BA and 3 digit numbers to CBA (ignoring edge cases)

Comment: @FDinoff - yes, well that's is consistent with the single example, and appears to be what the code is trying to do.  But beyond that, we are all **guessing** ... because the real requirements are missing from the question.

Comment: Thank you very much, actually I am trying to convert $123 to one hundred and twenty-three, but my problem was I just got one hundred.

Comment: @userNew - simple recursion is not a good approach for that problem.  The "grammar" of numbers is too complicated; e.g. consider whether you do or don't insert an "and".

Comment: @StephenC right, but actually I'm convert 123.00 so luckily I don't have to worry about that

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not correct, for starters, you don't even need to pass a string as a parameter - just build the string in the return values. Also, the logic for converting from integers to strings is overly complicated and *only* works if the integer contains the digits `1, 2, 3` in that exact order! Here's a simpler, working approach that processes each character in turn and works for integers with any digits:

```
public String recur(int x) {
    if (x <= 0)
        return "";
    return (char) (x % 10 + 'A' - 1) + recur(x / 10);
}
```

Explanation:

- The base case occurs when the integer is equal or less than zero, and we must return an empty string in such case
- The recursive step works as follows:

  - We obtain the current digit from the integer by taking the remainder: `x % 10`, and converting the digit to an uppercase character by adding `'A'` and subtracting `1`
  - We concatenate the previous result with the result of advancing the recursion, dividing the integer by `10`

Answer (score 0):

(This Answer is largely for the peanut gallery ...)

Here's my take on the "best" recursive solution to the problem as stated:

```
public String recur ( int x )
{
    if ( x >= 1 && x < 10 ) {
        return "A";
    } else if ( x >= 10 && x < 100 ) {
        return "B" + recur( x );
    } else if ( x >= 100 && x < 1000 ) {
        return "C" + recur( x );    
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}

System.err.println(recur(123));
```

or a bit more generally:

```
public String recur ( int x)
    return recur0( x, 0 );
}

public String recur0 ( int x, int i )
{
    if ( x <= 0 ) {
        return "";
    else {
        return recur0( x % 10, i + 1 ) + ((char) ('A' + i));
    } 
}

System.err.println(recur(123));
```

As you can see, no StringBuilder is needed.  At best, a StringBuilder is a micro-optimization.  It does not make the code any safer, or any more readable.  To illustrate, here's the first version redone using a StringBuilder

```
public void recur ( int x, StringBuilder sb )
{
    if ( x >= 1 && x < 10 ) {
        sb.append("A");
    } else if ( x >= 10 && x < 100 ) {
        sb.append("B");
        recur( x, sb );
    } else if ( x >= 100 && x < 1000 ) {
        sb.append("C");
        recur( x, sb );    
    } 
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
recur(123, sb);
System.err.println(sb.toString());
```

But the simplest solution for the problem as originally stated is this:

```
public String nonRecur(int x) {
    if ( x >= 1 && x < 10 ) {
        return "A";
    } else if ( x >= 10 && x < 100 ) {
        return "BA";
    } else if ( x >= 100 && x < 1000 ) {
        return "CBA";    
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}

System.err.println(nonRecur(123));
```

---

Note that there is considerable ambiguity in the way that the problem was stated, and @ÓscarLópez's solution is based on a *different* interpretation of the problem than mine.  He is mapping the digits of the numbers to letters, rather than using the letters to signify magnitude.

In fact, the OP's *actual* problem is neither of these interpretations, and I don't think that any of the Answers will actually help him ... even though they do answer his Question.